# Complex Types are not generated in details when viewing the WSDL from asmx or wcf service

Tags: web-services, wsdl, asmx, complextype

I have this class

```
public class Subject
{
    int ID;
    string Name;
    int Semester;
    int Grade;
}
```

I am using it in a .asmx and in .svc(wcf) web service. When invoking the service with the ?wsdl in browser i expect to see the complex type Subject with all its members but instead i see only a declaration for the complex type.

```
<xs:complexType name="Subject">
<xs:sequence/>
</xs:complexType> -> this is from the wcf service wsdl
```

`<s:complexType name="Subject"/>` -> this is from the asmx web service wsdl

In the wcf service the class has the [DataContract] attribute

how do i generate the wsdl to show me the complex type details with all members? what am i doing wrong?
Im using .NET 4 and VS2010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The XML Serializer pretty much only works with public read/write properties. Try this:

```
public class Subject
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public int Semester {get;set;}
    public int Grade {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: i cannot belive that i omited the 'public' keyword and didnt notice it. Thanks a lot!